# No password supplied by the callback handler for the user [wso2]

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a proxy service inlclued a sequence.
I process for authentication for proxy service with tag 
`<policy key="gov:/testPolicy"/>
    <enableSec/>`

In this sequence contain iterate mediator.
When call proxy service with authentication by soapUI then not reponse for client and have a error `Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No password supplied by the callback handler for the user : "wso2carbon"`

If have not  iterate mediator then have not error

This sequence
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="SendReceiveQueue" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property expression="get-property('Edxml_Organ_Id')" name="senderUnitId" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property expression="get-property('Edxml_Type')" name="applicationType" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property expression="get-property('Edxml_Record_Code')" name="recordCode" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property expression="$ctx:data_original" name="messagePl" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:edXML="http://www.mic.gov.vn/TBT/QCVN_102_2016" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property expression="$body" name="messagePlBody" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:edXML="http://www.mic.gov.vn/TBT/QCVN_102_2016" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <property name="QUEUE_ACTION_TYPE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="SENDER"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('messagePl')" name="messagePllogging" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        <property expression="get-property('messagePlBody')" name="messagePlloggingBody" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <iterate expression="$ctx:abc//edXML:To" id="abc" sequential="true" xmlns:edXML="http://www.mic.gov.vn/TBT/QCVN_102_2016" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="goi DSS" value="-------------------------------------------"/>
                    <property expression="//edXML:To/edXML:OrganId/text()" name="queue name"/>
                </log>
                <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                    <format>
                        <p:getQueueId xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                            <xs:in_unitId xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:in_unitId>
                            <xs:in_b2bType xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:in_b2bType>
                        </p:getQueueId>
                    </format>
                    <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//edXML:To/edXML:OrganId/text()"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="syn:get-property('Edxml_Type')"/>
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
                <call blocking="true">
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://cqdt-app3:8280/services/validateData"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </call>
                <property expression="//x:returnCode/x:MessageQueueId/text()" name="queue_name" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:x="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="lay xong tu dss" value="-------------------------------------------"/>
                    <property expression="$ctx:queue_name" name="ten queue lay ra"/>
                </log>
                <class name="com.vsc.ReceiveQueue">
                    <property name="password" value="admin"/>
                    <property name="queueName" value="testQueue1"/>
                    <property name="CF_NAME_PREFIX" value="connectionfactory."/>
                    <property name="CF_NAME" value="QueueConnectionFactory"/>
                    <property name="QPID_ICF" value="org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory"/>
                    <property name="CARBON_DEFAULT_HOSTNAME" value="cqdt-app3"/>
                    <property name="QUEUE_NAME_PREFIX" value="queue."/>
                    <property name="userName" value="admin"/>
                    <property name="CARBON_CLIENT_ID" value="carbon"/>
                    <property name="CARBON_DEFAULT_PORT" value="5675"/>
                    <property name="CARBON_VIRTUAL_HOST_NAME" value="carbon"/>
                </class>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="put xong vao queue" value="-------------------------------------------"/>
                    <property expression="$ctx:queue_name" name="ten queue ban xong"/>
                </log>
                <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                    <format>
                        <response>
                            <result>SUCCESS</result>
                        </response>
                    </format>
                    <args/>
                </payloadFactory>
                <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
                <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
                <header action="remove" name="To" scope="default"/>
                <send/>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
    <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <header action="remove" name="To" scope="default"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('messagePl')" name="1111555555555555555555555555551111111111111111111111111111111-------------------------------" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
</sequence>`

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried applying the policy on the endpoint directly?

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TQBsEndpoint">
   <address uri="http://cqdt-app3:8280/services/validateData" format="soap11">
      <enableSec policy="gov:testPolicy"/>
   </address>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: i removed below code: <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
                <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
                <header action="remove" name="To" scope="default"/>